# Contraction of indefinite articles

Tags: grammaire, contractions

I have just learned how to contract the definite articles in French:

à+le=au

à+les=aux

de+le=du

de+les=des

Is there a way of contracting the indefinite articles too?

à+un=?

à+une=?

de+un=?

de+une=?

Thank you.

Comment: Also, welcome to French Language Stack Exchange!

Comment: Thank you for welcoming me.

Answer (score 3):

*de un(e)* is nice and easy: we just contract it to *d'un(e)*. This is the usual strategy with the *e caduc* : *ne*, *me*, *le*, *te*, *se*, *que* all behave this way too.

*à un(e)* too gives rise to the problem of [hiatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_hiatus), which French usually eschews and avoids by liaison or contraction. When the first vowel is not an *e caduc*, there isn't a formally accepted contraction, but you will see lots of informal variants like *t'es* for *tu es*. However, I've never seen a writing convention to combine *à un(e)*, either formally or informally. But the vowels will still end up squished together in speech at regular speed and be very hard to distinguish.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Luke. Can you please provide an example for contraction of "que" in an "e caduc" situation?

Comment: @JaneB. « Achetez votre billet maintenant ! Il n'en reste qu'un ! »